# Managing common code used in multiple SQL Statements

Tags: sql, version-control, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use SQL Developer to create PL/SQL statements querying our corporate Oracle 10g database and I've found that there are many common components to these queries, such as a set of joins or criteria that are identical in many statements. My problem is that when I update the code in one of these sections, I have to keep track of and manually update every other statement that uses that same common code so that all statements are consistent with eachother and mutually accurate.

I have not yet implemented a source-code control system. Is there a source-code control system (SVN, TFS or otherwise) that will allow me to manage these 'dynamic' *sub-sections* of various SQL statements systematically? My thought is that, once I update a common code block, those updates will cascade through and be updated in any of my other statements that use that same *common code*.

If such a feature does not exist, what are your suggestions for managing dozens, if not hundreds of distinct SQL statements in the manner that I have described?

Comment: You can use views if you find yourself querying the same joined tables over and over and over.

Comment: Indeed, views are good when the data/criteria is consistent, but in my case, the code is constantly changing. As the business/reporting needs change, I modify the criteria or other code to reflect the latest needs, and do so in many different statements that drive different but similar reports.

Comment: Sure, you can use a version control system to manage bits-n-pieces of queries - column lists, predicates, etc - but I think that trying to hang all these bits together in a consistent fashion may prove to be an exercise in frustration.  My first take on this is - you need to provide an app that allows your users to specify the queries they want to run.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Good point @bob-jarvis, your suggestion sounds like the concept of a dynamic _dashboard_ of sorts that could programmatically generate a dynamic SQL statement and/or the subsequent results. I don't have the resources to write said app at this time, but I'll keep that in consideration as a possible future solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE example_one
(
    eo_id    NUMBER
,   eo_value NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO example_one(eo_id, eo_value) VALUES(1, 10);    

CREATE TABLE example_two
(
    et_id    NUMBER
,   et_value NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO example_two(et_id, et_value) VALUES(1, 20);    

CREATE TABLE db_sql_statements
(
    s_stmt_id NUMBER
,   s_stmt    VARCHAR2(4000) /* should be CLOB - it can exceed 4000 CHAR */
);

INSERT INTO db_sql_statements(s_stmt_id, s_stmt) VALUES(1,'SELECT ~[columns_list_#00001]~ FROM ~[source_tables_#00001]~ ~[ON join_conditions_#00001]~ ~[WHERE where_conditions_#00001]~');
);

CREATE TABLE db_sql_parameters
(
    p_param_id VARCHAR2(4000)
,   p_param    VARCHAR2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO db_sql_parameters(p_param_id, p_param) VALUES('columns_list_#00001',     'eo.eo_id, eo.eo_value + et.et_value');
INSERT INTO db_sql_parameters(p_param_id, p_param) VALUES('source_tables_#00001',    'example_one eo JOIN example_two et');
INSERT INTO db_sql_parameters(p_param_id, p_param) VALUES('join_conditions_#00001',  'ON eo.eo_id = et.et_id');
INSERT INTO db_sql_parameters(p_param_id, p_param) VALUES('where_conditions_#00001', 'WHERE 1 = 1');

CREATE TABLE db_sql_stmt_param_bridge
(
    pb_stmt_id  NUMBER
,   pb_param_r  NUMBER
,   pb_param_id VARCHAR2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO db_sql_stmt_param_bridge(pb_stmt_id, pb_param_r, pb_param_id) VALUES(1, 1, 'columns_list_#00001');
INSERT INTO db_sql_stmt_param_bridge(pb_stmt_id, pb_param_r, pb_param_id) VALUES(1, 2, 'source_tables_#00001');
INSERT INTO db_sql_stmt_param_bridge(pb_stmt_id, pb_param_r, pb_param_id) VALUES(1, 3, 'join_conditions_#00001');
INSERT INTO db_sql_stmt_param_bridge(pb_stmt_id, pb_param_r, pb_param_id) VALUES(1, 4, 'where_conditions_#00001');

SELECT  s.s_stmt, p.p_param_id, p.p_param
FROM    db_sql_statements s
JOIN    db_sql_stmt_param_bridge pb
ON      s.s_stmt_id = pb.pb_stmt_id
JOIN    db_sql_parameters p
ON      pb.pb_param_id = p.p_param_id
;
/*
SELECT ~[columns_list_#00001]~ FROM ~[source_tables_#00001]~ ~[ON join_conditions_#00001]~ ~[WHERE where_conditions_#00001]~    columns_list_#00001 eo.eo_id, eo.eo_value + et.et_value
SELECT ~[columns_list_#00001]~ FROM ~[source_tables_#00001]~ ~[ON join_conditions_#00001]~ ~[WHERE where_conditions_#00001]~    source_tables_#00001    example_one eo JOIN example_two et
SELECT ~[columns_list_#00001]~ FROM ~[source_tables_#00001]~ ~[ON join_conditions_#00001]~ ~[WHERE where_conditions_#00001]~    join_conditions_#00001  ON eo.eo_id = et.et_id
SELECT ~[columns_list_#00001]~ FROM ~[source_tables_#00001]~ ~[ON join_conditions_#00001]~ ~[WHERE where_conditions_#00001]~    where_conditions_#00001 WHERE 1 = 1
*/

SELECT  REPLACE
        (
            REPLACE
            (
                REPLACE
                (
                    REPLACE
                    (
                        s_stmt
                    ,   '~[columns_list_#00001]~'
                    ,   p_param
                    )
                ,   '~[source_tables_#00001]~'
                ,   lead_p_param
                )
            ,   '~[ON join_conditions_#00001]~'
            ,   lead_p_param2
            )
        ,   '~[WHERE where_conditions_#00001]~'
        ,   lead_p_param3
        )
FROM
(
        SELECT  s.s_stmt
        ,       p.p_param_id
        ,       p.p_param
        ,       LEAD(p.p_param)    OVER (PARTITION BY s.s_stmt ORDER BY pb.pb_param_r) AS lead_p_param
        ,       LEAD(p.p_param, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY s.s_stmt ORDER BY pb.pb_param_r) AS lead_p_param2
        ,       LEAD(p.p_param, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY s.s_stmt ORDER BY pb.pb_param_r) AS lead_p_param3
        ,       ROW_NUMBER()       OVER (PARTITION BY s.s_stmt ORDER BY pb.pb_param_r) AS r_number
        FROM    db_sql_statements s
        JOIN    db_sql_stmt_param_bridge pb
        ON      s.s_stmt_id = pb.pb_stmt_id
        JOIN    db_sql_parameters p
        ON      pb.pb_param_id = p.p_param_id
)
WHERE   r_number = 1
;    
-- SELECT eo.eo_id, eo.eo_value + et.et_value FROM example_one eo JOIN example_two et ON eo.eo_id = et.et_id WHERE 1 = 1

SELECT eo.eo_id, eo.eo_value + et.et_value FROM example_one eo JOIN example_two et ON eo.eo_id = et.et_id WHERE 1 = 1;
-- 1    30
```

Run it from PL/SQL and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.
I have done something similar when I was writing db framework.

Comment: I love this concept of keeping the pieces in tables in the DBMS, especially since it allows the dynamic generation to happen at runtime. The code could be updated in said tables meaning the already-distributed statements would not need to be re-written. Thanks for the insightful suggestion.